# Reading Variables from SEO Friendly URLS

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on a custom theme template for Word Press and I was wondering how to read the variables from the SEO friendly URLS. The website admin can choose between standard URLS `http://yourdomain.com/?p=10`, which is easy enough to read from with `$_GET['p']`. But how do I go about reading from the SEO friendly urls `http://yourdomain.com/your-page-name/`.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried dumping the contents of `$_GET` using `var_dump($_GET)` to see what it contains? You may find that the data you seek is there. The SEO-friendly URLs act as a mask over the "real" URL.

Answer (score 0):

**Are you on the page** `http://yourdomain.com/your-page-name/` trying to get the `$_GET['p']` value? Just call `$_GET['p']` it should work and should have a value of `your-page-name`. To my understanding mod rewrite only masks the look of the address for the browser bar, but the url is on server side still handled the same way.

**Or are you on a different page** and you are examining the link `http://yourdomain.com/your-page-name/` trying to figure out how to get `your-page-name` as a variable? For that I would suggest you do either a string split, string position, explode, or regular expression... Many options I think.